# Magento 2 DropdownDialog widget showing dropdown when the page load without onclick

Tags: jquery, magento2.4.1, popup

I am using https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_dialog.html if the page refreshes the drop-down popup come 1 second on the page, how to solve this issue on the home page.

My settings:

```
"dropdownDialog": {
        "appendTo": "[data-block=dropdown]",
        "triggerTarget":"[data-trigger=trigger]",
        "timeout": 2000,
        "closeOnMouseLeave": false,
        "closeOnEscape": true,
        "triggerClass": "active",
        "parentClass": "active",
        "buttons": []
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use autoOpen: false, or just remove it

As I think you have copy-paste it from Magento doc they keep it as true.

Comment: pls see my updated post, still i am getting that issue like if page load that popup will come 1 second on page.

Comment: And then get hide?? In that case put inline display none and then remove that using js after DOM get load

Comment: Can you pls explain in detail, it really appreciated?

Comment: you mean window.onload()

Comment: Any help thanks @Nilesh Dubey

Comment: Sorry for late reply Yes. If you user jquery then $(document).ready() will do the trick

Comment: I am using custom phtml file under app/design/frontend/zero/my_theme/Magento_Theme/template/custom.phtml, is it $(document).ready() will work here?

Comment: Yes just wrap it with require js with jquery deps

Comment: As per magento docs i want hind this id "minicart-content-wrapper" when page load,, https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_dialog.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120962/discussion-between-zus-and-nilesh-dubey).

Answer (score 1):

try moving `block-minicart` in `minicart-wrapper`

from

```
<div data-block="dropdown" class="minicart-wrapper">
    <button type="button" class="action" data-trigger="trigger">
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Click Here'"></span>
    </button>
</div>
<div class="block block-minicart"
     data-mage-init='{
        "dropdownDialog": {
            "appendTo": "[data-block=dropdown]",
            "triggerTarget":"[data-trigger=trigger]",
            "timeout": 2000,
            "closeOnMouseLeave": false,
            "closeOnEscape": true,
            "triggerClass": "active",
            "parentClass": "active",
            "buttons": []
        }
     }'>
    <div id="minicart-content-wrapper">
        Here is our content
    </div>
</div>
```

to

```
<div data-block="dropdown" class="minicart-wrapper">
    <button type="button" class="action" data-trigger="trigger">
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Click Here'"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="block block-minicart"
         data-mage-init='{
        "dropdownDialog": {
            "appendTo": "[data-block=dropdown]",
            "triggerTarget":"[data-trigger=trigger]",
            "timeout": 2000,
            "closeOnMouseLeave": false,
            "closeOnEscape": true,
            "triggerClass": "active",
            "parentClass": "active",
            "buttons": []
        }
     }'>
        <div id="minicart-content-wrapper">
            Here is our content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```